# Delete specific array string in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

how can I delete all that string instead of writing nothing? because nothing actually means a line with nothing, but the line exists. I want it to no longer exist!

```vb
Dim textfile() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\textfile.txt"))

For i As Integer = 0 To textfile.Count - 1
    If textfile(i).Length > 1 Then
        textfile(i) = Nothing 'here i want to delete
    End if
Next
```

Comment: Two questions: how do I delete an empty string from an array of strings? how do I write an array of strings to a file?

Comment: That is very inefficient, use StreamReader.ReadLine() and List(Of String) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ to select only lines that are not empty:

```vb
Dim textfile = IO.File.ReadAllLines(IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "textfile.txt"))
Dim filteredTextFile = textfile.Where(Function(line) Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(line)).ToArray()
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nUpjEH

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter out the empty lines, and write to a file. The accepted answer does the first part of this, so here is the complete solution

```vb
Dim textFile = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt")
Dim fixedLines = textFile.Where(Function(line) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
File.WriteAllLines("filename.txt", fixedLines)
```

@HansPassant pointed out in a comment that this is not the most efficient solution. Here is another way to do it using StreamReader / StreamWriter

```vb
Dim lines As New List(Of String)()
Using sr As New StreamReader("filename.txt")
    While Not sr.EndOfStream
        Dim line = sr.ReadLine()
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) Then lines.Add(line)
    End While
End Using
Using sw As New StreamWriter("filename.txt")
    For Each line In lines
        sw.WriteLine(line)
    Next
End Using
```

However, using a 1kb file ~1000 line file with a few empty lines, my system takes about 18ms for the first method, and 18 ms for the second (each averaged 1000 times). So at least in my system, in this case, there isn't much of a difference. See https://designingefficientsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/efficient-file-io-from-csharp/ for further analysis if efficiency is a concern.

Comment: You should specifically note that `File.ReadAllLines` must be used - if `File.ReadLines` were used then this code would fail.

Comment: what if instead of `list<string>` you just write line into the `sw` as you read it?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, I was just building off the OP idea

Comment: @T.S. I am overwriting the same file which seemed like the OP's intent, so that wouldn't work. Maybe if it was a new file...

Comment: Yes ^^^^^ sure.

Answer (score -1):

According to this `If textfile(i).Length > 1 Then` you seem want only short lines to remain. And you setting `nothing` only to long ones

Do this using LINQ

```
Dim onlyShortLines() as String = 
   textfile.Where(Func(x) x.Length = 1).Select(Func(x) x).ToArray()
```

Comment: You're comparing the length, when the user wants to know if the line is a blank line; presumably a line with just space characters should be striped. Also, you have a typo: `Func(x)` should be `Function(x)`. Finally, there's no need for `.Select(Function(x) x)` that is just redundant.

Comment: @David You're right, And I guess I did not make myself clear enough - the point here is that OP's code did not support check for empty lines. It is definitely implied that `null` should be set on the lines longer than 1 character.  If you read the Q again and then the code provided - combine the 2 and look - OP takes lines, selects those longer than 1 and sets them to null. Then in the question it asks how to get rid of those. If you read the question and the code- you will see that my answer is correct. I did exactly what OP asked for. **It is OP had not asked the Q correctly given the code**